# ENOLOCAL: can't find package.json file after publishing npm package

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

**Ecosystem**

```
using npm@6.1.0
using node@v8.11.1
```

**Context**

I have a JS project that includes a local dependencie :

*package.json :*

```
"dependencies": {
   "my_local_module": "file:my_local_module"
},
```

Then, I published the project as `npm` private package : so far everything is OK.

**Issue**

When I try to install my private package, I have this issue :

```
33 error code ENOLOCAL
34 error Could not install from "node_modules\@my_scope\my_project\my_local_module" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Of course, the `package.json` file exists. When I try to copy manually the project from gitHub instead of installing it with `npm`, it works perfectly fine but I really would like to make it works with :

```
npm install @my_scope\my_project
```

Is there a specific way to publish packages when they include local dependencies or anything like that ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you include the file structure of the project?

Comment: @Sierra: did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete your package-lock.json file

I had the same problem and error. The package-lock.json was still doing a reference to "file:my_local_module".
I deleted it and re npm installed the module to make it work

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that this solves the problem?

Comment: I had the same problem and error. The package-lock.json was still doing a reference to »file:my_local_module ». I deleted it and npm installed the module to make it work.

Comment: Please add all such information to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I found a report of a similar issue within the npm cli github

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1756

It appears this may be an issue with npm v6 (I was using version 6.14.12).  Updating npm to v7 seems to have solved this issue for me.